# Using Terminal to remove wildcards

Tags: delete, macosx

I'm a bit new to this, I've used `IRAF` before but that was a couple years ago. My question is how would I go about removing certain files. Sample of files goes as is:

```
0001Reduce_Proc.fits

0001Reduce.fits

0002Reduce_Proc.fits

0002Reduce.fits

0003Reduce_Proc.fits

0003Reduce.fits
```

I want to remove the Reduce.fits files, but I can't seem to find a way to do this without removing the Reduce_Proc.fits.

I tried

```
 rm *Reduce.fits
```

but it doesn't work. Any pointers?

Comment: Welcome! `rm *Reduce.fits ` should work. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: It deletes all the files, when I don't want that to happen.

Comment: @NoTimeForUsernames it should not do so - did you accidentally add a space between the `*` and the `Reduce.fits`?

Answer (score 0):

Rename each of the undesired files to a filename used by nothing else in that directory, e.g. 
`mv 0???Reduce.fits 0???WileEcoyoteAcme.fits` then do 
`rm 0???WileEcoyoteAcme.fits`